# Multiple fields for one attribute

Tags: php, forms, symfony

Say I have three fields for a user to enter a date: day, month, and year. (Likely not the best way, but I'm using it for this example). If I try to `$form->bind()` the user's request, Symfony will try and look for a `->setMonth()` method on my model, which doesn't exist.

How do I tell Symfony that I want to run the input through `strtotime()` (or any other any other arbitrary code or method) before, and then map the new output to `setDate()`?

Comment: Are you really trying to input a date or is this just an example?

Comment: Date was just an example. I was more looking for a way to intercept data before it's passed onto the setters. In my specific case, there's three inputs, which are serialised together and then stored as the value of the attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you need to tell symfony that these fields do not have a corresponding Entity property. This is done with the 'property_path' option doing something like this

```
$builder->add("field1", "text", array(
    "property_path" => false
));
```

In your controller, once you have checked that the form is valid and before persisting the entity you can get the values of these fields using something like:

```
$field1 = $form->get('field1')->getData();
```

and then use these values to construct your entity property as you need, for example:

```
$entity->setWhatever($field1.$field2.$field3);
```

If you need to do some sort of validation on these fields, your best option is to write a callback validator.

Comment: Use: 'mapped' => false instead of "property_path" => false.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use plural html fields just for one property "date" of your user class.

In the reference: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html

A field date can be rendered as you want thanks to the option "widget".

In your case, you want 3 fields, you have to set the value "choice" (renders three select inputs. The order of the selects is defined in the pattern option).

Here the code in the form class:

```
$builder->add('date', 'date', array(
    'widget' => 'choice',
));
```

Also you want to get a timestamp ("strtotime") after the form is submitted:

```
$builder->add('date', 'date', array(
    'widget' => 'choice',
    'input' => 'timestamp',
));
```

You can play with other options, for example, to get just a text field on which you activate a JS datepicker !