# Multiple form fields for 1 attribute

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-2.7

I have an entity `Application`.

I'd like to link my applications with some `Server` entity.

But in this link, there's some information like an integer for the port...

In order to do this, I created another entity `LinkAppliServ`.

In `Application` :

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="MyBundle\Entity\LinkAppliServ", mappedBy="appli",cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $links;
```

in `LinkAppliServ` :

```
/**
 * @var \MyBundle\Entity\Application
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MyBundle\Entity\Application", inversedBy="links")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="appli_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $appli;

/**
 * @var \MyBundle\Entity\Server
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MyBundle\Entity\Server", inversedBy="links")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="serv_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $serv;
```

Now, In `Application`'s form, I would like to have multiple fields for my attribute `$links` (because I want a filter on my `Server`'s type (which is an attribut of `Server`).

I tried to add as many attributes as needed, but it doesn't work (I want only 1 table...)
I tried to create as many forms as needed, does not work too...

What I want is something like that :
`ApplicationType` :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('links', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new LinkAppliServType(),  //filter on Server's type1
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true
            'label' => 'server type 1'
        ))
        ->add('links', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new LinkAppliServType_2(), //filter on Server's type2
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true
            'label' => 'server type 2'
        ))
        // and much more... ^^
```

How would you do it ?
Thanks !

Comment: I think that this answer might be what you are looking for (or not) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12250626/multiple-fields-for-one-attribute

Comment: @StasParshin kind of.. With this answer, I have to create as forms as needed I guess ? Is there a better way to do it ? Something more maintainable (ex: check Server's Type and create my forms "automatically" ? Then I can get values with a foreach or something like that ?